# Cannot import YAML from Ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to use ruamel.yaml and am using this code straight from the ruamel's documentation but I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ruameltest.py", line 12, in 
    yaml = YAML()
NameError: name 'YAML' is not defined

I am using Linux (RHEL)

Python 3.4.9

rpm package: python34-ruamel-yaml-0.13.14-1.el7.x86_64

How could I fix this issue?

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = """\
# example
name:
  # details
  family: Smith   # very common
  given: Alice    # one of the siblings
"""

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(inp)
code['name']['given'] = 'Bob'

yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Works fine for me in in both Python 2.7 and 3.7

Comment: What is your Ruamel version?

Comment: ruamel.yaml-0.15.96 - the fact that the import works would make it very unlikely you'd get this error, even if YAML wasn't what you expected it to be, regardless of the package version. - My guess is that the import is somehow not really running.  Maybe put a print statement on either side of it just to be sure, or move it just before the affected line.  All nonsense, I know, but then so is the result you're getting.  Computers are often baffling beasts.

Comment: Are you running this at the command line or in an IDE?  If the latter, I'd try running the script at the command line to make sure you get the same result and it isn't your IDE doing something funny.  - very strange

Comment: I'm running it on the terminal

Comment: I am using python 3.4.9 and the name of the package for ruamel.yaml is "python34-ruamel-yaml-0.13.14-1.el7.x86_64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system installed ruamel.yaml version is severely outdated, it is now (May 2019) at 0.15.96. The API that introduced the `YAML` class, that your program can't find was introduced two years ago.

Additionally your Python (3.4) has been end-of-life since 2019-03-18.

You can either follow the old, PyYAML, API:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import RoundTripLoader, RoundTripDumper, load, dump

inp = """\
# example
name:
  # details
  family: Smith   # very common
  given: Alice    # one of the siblings
"""

data = load(inp, Loader=RoundTripLoader)
data['name']['given'] = 'Bob'
dump(data, sys.stdout, Dumper=RoundTripDumper)
```

which gives:

```
# example
name:
  # details
  family: Smith   # very common
  given: Bob      # one of the siblings
```

Please note that you load *data* from YAML not *code*.

It would of course be better to use an up-to-date version of `ruamel.yaml` and a maintained
version of Python. If you cannot install a newer Python version, or compile it yourself, you
still can install a newer  version of `ruamel.yaml`:

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/venv/yamltest
$ source ~/venv/yamltest/bin/activate
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install 'ruamel.yaml<=0.15.94'
```

And then you should be able to use your program as is.

newer versions, released after 0.15.94, do not include `.whl` files
for Python 3.4, those versions will probably still work, but you might
need to have a compiler installed to make use of the C extensions, and 
if you do you should just download and install Python 3.7

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Where can I find the documentation to older Ruamel.yaml versions? especially for customizing thing such as dump spaces and indentations?

Comment: You can find the older builds of the documentation on read-the-docs, but you would need to try out which build is which ruamel.yaml version (or guess based on release related to build date). Indentation/space control has increased in 0.15, so you don't want older versions.